# Utils.cpp function and getting prefilled array from text file

Tags: c, arrays

This file needs to read a text file with numbers on each line, and preload the values from the text file into myArray. It also needs to read the integer for arraySize, so that it can be used to calculate the mean and median. The code is in c, but the teacher uses c++ file names and doesn't want us t change it. I also want to total the numbers, but when executed it doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Utils.cpp"

int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    int myArray[]={};
    // declare a string to hold the name of the file
    // that will be read into your statsArray
    char statsFile[] = "2005.txt";              /* file to be read in */
    int arraySize = getFileSize(statsFile);     /* determine size of file */

    //dynamically declare statsArray based on size of file
    int *statsArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*arraySize);
    // initialize arrays with zero values       
        initializeArray(myArray, arraySize);

    //load array from file      
        loadArray(myArray, arraySize, statsFile);

    // sum stats array
    int total=0;
    for(int x=0;x<myArray[arraySize-1];x++){
        total+=myArray[x]; //adds each element of array to total
    }
    printf("%i",total);
```

Here is the utils.cpp that was provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getFileSize(char fileName[])
{
    FILE    *fr;        /* declare the file pointer */
    int     c;          /*Nb int (not char) for the EOF */
    int     newlineCount = 0;

    // open the file to count the lines
    fr = fopen(fileName, "rt");
    // count the newline characters 
    while ( (c=fgetc(fr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c =='\n')
            newlineCount++;
    }
    return newlineCount;
}

void loadArray(int list[], int size, char fileName[])
{

    FILE    *fr;        // declare the file pointer 
    int     count = 0;  // running line count
    char line[80];

    fr = fopen(fileName, "rt");

    while(fgets(line, 80, fr) != NULL)
    {
        // get a line, p to 80 chars fr. done if NULL 
        sscanf(line, "%i", &list[count]);
        count++;
    }
} 

void initializeArray(int list[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        list[i] = 0;
    }
}

void sortArray(int list[], int size)
{
    int tempNumber;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i +1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(list[i] > list[j])
            {
                tempNumber = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = tempNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; however *"I am having trouble"* and then showing code is not considered to be an appropriate form for a question.  You must describe what the problem is.  For instance: Are you having problems *compiling* the code?  Is it compiling and working on some inputs, but not others?  Please note that there is an EDIT button on the question where you can add more details, and consider reading the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  *(Also, C and C++ are different languages, and .CPP extensions usually imply C++...so make it clear which you mean.)*

Comment: Thank you for editing a bit.  However, it is not possible to reproduce your problem...because you haven't provided everything involved.  You mention a file `2005.txt` which we don't have.  BUT before pasting that file into your question, please read about what makes a good question with [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...which means *not* just pasting your situation entirely, but doing the work to minimize the sample to the point where you clearly identify a specific misunderstanding.  *(Don't give up, these techniques will serve you for life!)*